# Regarding error in servlet while deploying

Tags: servlets

I have developed a simple servlet as shown below..in eclipse by choosing dynamci project in eclipse ...

servlet is..

```
package com.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class Myservlet2 extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            System.out.println("Servlet 2 of App2 invoked...");
             response.setContentType("text/html");
             PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
             out.println("This output is generated by servlet2 of app2");
             out.close();

        }
    }
```

and the  web.xml is...

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Myservlet2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.demo.Myservlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Myservlet2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Upon deploying it on tomcat through eclipse I got the following error..

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.Myservlet2
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please how this can be corrected.Thanks in advance

Comment: It is better if you start reading some good tutorials. You are having almost same type of errors in all four five questions you have posted

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class `com.demo.MyServlet2` is present in `WEB-INF/classes` or in the library jar located in `WEB-INF/lib`